# Google Map V2 Android and iOS place latlng decimal places

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

There is an Android as well as iOS application that I am working on.
Both the applications use google's PlaceAutocomplete controller to get a location's lat-long. In iOS we get lat-long upto 6 decimal places sometimes 5 also. Where as in android we get more than 6 decimal places. The precision of the same location coordinate for Android and iOS differs.

```
For example consider location Pune
             Android Latlng: 18.520431,73.856744
                 iOS Latlng: 18.52043,73.856744
```

So as you can see there is difference between the precision of latitudes of the same location.

Is there a way to avoid this as my application needs comparison of these lat-longs?

Answer (score 8):

You should not rely on the precision of the coordinates to compare them because they can change or, as you experiment, vary between platforms.

Instead, you can set a tolerance to determine if two locations are the same. For example:

```
float YOUR_TOLERANCE = 1; // 1 meter
if (location.distanceTo(otherLocation) < YOUR_TOLERANCE) {
    // Both locations are considered the same
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In android also there is three type of location :

1. GPS_PROVIDER
2. NETWORK_PROVIDER
3. PASSIVE_PROVIDER

So, as per my coding experience i come to know that if you use :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, new MyLocationListener());
```

you will get long precision of decimal like more then 14+ and if you will you use fusion of them with this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, my_google_listener);
```

then you will get 6 to 7 digit of precision. try it !!!