# Android's most accurate Location API

Tags: android, location

In order to work, my app requires a location API.
I intend use the Mapbox platform to customize its design (since Google Maps
does not provide this level of customization, as far as I am concerned).

Documentation says that we should use Google Play API when building location
apps:

> The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the  Android
>   framework location APIs (android.location)  as a way of adding
>   location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android
>   framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the
>   Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.

My question is:
Is Google Play API the most efficient API when it comes to GPS accuracy?
Or should I use the LocationManager and LocationListener way of doing it?

I need accuracy. Which one should I use?
Thanks.

Comment: so if it is accurate but drains the battery are you ok with that?

Comment: At first, yes! Is that the reason why they recommend Google Play API?

Comment: I think `fusedlocation` (aka the google location api) is designed to be more efficient in terms of battery usage and network. I haven't seen any benchmarks so this is all subjective and speculative; the accuracy I get from `fusedlocation` is more than enough and I wouldn't try anything unless it performs horribly.

Comment: @muratgu How much accurate in meters?

Comment: I don't know how accurate.

Comment: Fused location uses network and GPS to provide less accuracy but less power drain than GPS.  How accurate it is depends on a lot of factors.  GPS alon is accurate to about 5-10m, but depends on phone hardware, clear line of sight, atmospheric conditions, etc.  Fused location will be less accurate, and have many of the same conditions.  Network will be least, to within say 200m but will use almost no power.  Both Fused and Network require network connectivity though (GPS doesn't).

Comment: "Is that the reason why they recommend Google Play API?" -> Yes. But not only. Also if things goes thru Play Services Google have explicit control over what to do with that location. Also to use it for further data harvesting, share to the world, use for targeting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In android also there are three types of location :

1. GPS_PROVIDER
2. NETWORK_PROVIDER
3. PASSIVE_PROVIDER

So, as per my coding experience I came to know that if you use :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, new MyLocationListener());
```

you will get precision upto 14+ decimal places.

But if you use fusion of them like this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, my_google_listener);
```

you will get precision upto 6 to 7 decimal places. try it !!! [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523498/5432730)

But note few things here that, GPS Provider takes time to fetch location while Google Location is much faster as it gets data from API call to its google server database.

GPS works offline while google provider gets the location via mobile or wifi data.

Comment: But - does decimal place count correlate to actual location accuracy? My guess would be no.

Comment: ^ Yes!, decimal place count affects the accuracy of location. More precise coordinates mean more accurate location.

Comment: No more precise coordinates does not mean more accurate, it just means more decimal places. The number of decimal places should be adjusted according to accuracy, however I see no facts here that indicate that is so.

Answer (score 6):

Use [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) and set LocationRequest priority to [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

This is newest API for accurate location fetch and google suggest to use the same.

Check Accuracy details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider).

Basically Google play services API has intelligence to get accurate location by fusing GPS+NetworkProvider+passive providers.

Answer (score 3):

[FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) is deprecated.You should use [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and you should add `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission,not `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to get the most accurate location.

And read [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html) article to understand why `FusedLocationProviderClient` is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the Google Services Location API are preferable to use in following aspects:

- they deal with user settings, choosing the best available location provider. If you choose to work with LocationManager directly, your code will need to handle that.
- you might expect to get a better location with less power usage, as Google regularly updates their algorithms for determining location using WiFi, cell towers, etc.

In my experience, using Google Services, location with accuracy sufficient for a mapping application (that is some tens meters) in many cases does not require GPS data. That might also be the case with FusedLocationProvider, though, maybe with an exception for the battery usage numbers.

To conclude, if you don't have arguments to NOT use Google Services (such as - you target a country where they are not available, or want to distribute via alternative markets) you should use their Location API.